# Questions on scull_follow function in linux device drivers 3rd edition

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I never found the definition for scull_follow in the book, so I'm trying to understand it based off a github repo(https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3).
Here is the code I am trying to understand:

```c
struct scull_qset *scull_follow(struct scull_dev *dev, int n) {
  struct scull_qset *qs = dev->data;

  /* Allocate first qset explicitly if need be */
  if (!qs) { // if NULL
    qs = dev->data = kmalloc(sizeof(struct scull_qset), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (qs == NULL)
      return NULL;  /* Never mind */
    memset(qs, 0, sizeof(struct scull_qset));
  }

  /* Then follow the list */
  while (n--) {
    if (!qs->next) {
      qs->next = kmalloc(sizeof(struct scull_qset), GFP_KERNEL);
      if (qs->next == NULL)
        return NULL;  /* Never mind */
      memset(qs->next, 0, sizeof(struct scull_qset));
    }
    qs = qs->next;
    continue;
  }
  return qs;
}
```

Here is struct `scull_qset`:

```c
struct scull_qset {
  void **data;
  struct scull_qset *next;
};
```

Conceptually, I understand that all `scull_follow` does is that it follows the list up to the right position so that you know where to start reading/writing.
I'm mainly confused on this part of the code.

```c
 /* Allocate first qset explicitly if need be */
  if (!qs) { // if NULL
    qs = dev->data = kmalloc(sizeof(struct scull_qset), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (qs == NULL)
      return NULL;  /* Never mind */
    memset(qs, 0, sizeof(struct scull_qset));
  }
```

Let's say the user opens this driver and attempts to read from it first without writing. that should mean that it should go into the if statement and allocate some memory. Then, why is there a second check for if `qs` is `NULL` or not? Won't it always be not NULL because it was allocated some memory?

After that what is the `memset` function for? I understand that it copies 0 into `qs`, but what is the point of that other than initializing this memory region? Is it so that when you call the `copy_to_user` function in your read function it'll know that because it is filled with 0s, nothing of 'value' has been written to it so you will just get a blank output when reading, assuming the first operation you do is reading?

Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: the point of the 2nd thing is to ensure the memory backing the structure has valid, known values - in this case null pointers - instead of being uninitialised garbage that would be undefined behaviour to read. doing this on newly allocated memory is common. AFAICS, it's only worth _not_ doing if the code is a performance bottleneck and you can be extremely confident that all downstream users will assign valid values to the structure before reading it.

Comment: I see, so it's basically a safety check.

Comment: the 2nd thing is safety _insurance_, more like. not sure what the 1st is; i can't find any signs that `kmalloc()` can return `NULL`, and so as you said, it shouldn't ever `return` early there. but maybe i missed something.

Comment: @underscore_d `kmalloc()` can surely return `NULL` on multiple occasions, the simplest one is [in case the request is too large](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.8/source/mm/slab.c#L3650).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
qs = dev->data = kmalloc(sizeof(struct scull_qset), GFP_KERNEL);
if (qs == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

Is standard C programming good practice: whenever a function can fail, you always need to check the return value. This is true for any kind of function that can fail, not only `malloc()` and friends. In this case, `kmalloc()` can fail to allocate memory, returning `NULL`, so the code is checking for that error. If that happens, the function safely aborts execution by doing a `return NULL;`, and the caller will then handle that as needed.

This:

```
memset(qs, 0, sizeof(struct scull_qset));
```

Is standard kernel programming good practice: whenever you allocate uninitialized memory (like `kmalloc()` does), it could contain sensitive kernel data. You *never* want uninitialized data to reach userspace through a `copy_to_user()` or similar calls. In order to avoid this, you need to make sure to initialize it before making it available to userspace. Filling it with zeroes using `memset()` is one of the simplest way to do this.

In the case an user program does a `read` as the first syscall on the scull driver, it would just read a bunch of `0` bytes.